# Loading data from file using fstream

Tags: c++, sequence, fstream

In the file sequences.txt there are 100 sequences described with two rows. The first one says about the amount of numbers in this sequence while the second one contains of numbers in this sequence(data is sepearated with one space). For example the first four lines are:

*5

1 3 6 7 9

5

17 22 27 32 37*

Could you tell me how I can load those data using fstream library so that I would be able to do some mathematical operations like calculating the difference in each sequence or their sums? I suppose I have to use two arrays, one for the amount of numbers in each sequnce and the other one for numbers in each sequence. Thanks.

Comment: Check code ask if any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have code a general solution which will take your file in 2D jagged array. You have now all data in your final Array you can do any task what you want.

**File**

```
5
1 3 6 7 9
5
17 22 27 32 37
6 
1 2 3 4 5 6
3
13 45 67
```

**Code to get data in 2D Array.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    ifstream in("File.txt");
    int count = 4; //Your number of test cases here as you said 100 or 200
    int *sizes = new int[count]; // all szies for your 1D arrays
    int **Array = new int*[count]; //Main 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        in>>sizes[i]; //taking size for 1 row
        Array[i] = new int[sizes[i]]; //Making arrays 
        for (int j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++)
        {
            in >> Array[i][j]; //getting values of row
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++)
        {
            cout << Array[i][j] << " "; //Printing Final Array [i,j]
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //Now you have your final array in Array which is 2D Jagged Array You Can Do What Ever You Want.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) //memory release
        delete[] Array[i];
    delete[] Array;
    delete[] sizes;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get your idea and that is great but I am looking for a little bit shorter and maybe easier way to sovle this problem as it is likeley to be needed on my A Level exam and the time there is limited. So if anyone can describe antoher way to solve it, I will be grateful.

Comment: It  can be shorten if you give total number of test cases in start of file then we do not need to put a while loop which counts total test cases: and if you say that every line have same number of numbers in your case as every line have 5 numbers so it will more short it. I can make it more short if you are allowed to put no. of test cases in start of file and you are allowed to fix size of every line of numbers.

Comment: I have got 200 lines there. Unfortunately, the amount of numbers in sequences is from 5 to 100 so it is not constant.

Comment: 200 total lines or 200 cases ? 
I mean
5
1 2 3 4 5 
This whole is one line or these are 2 lines ?

Comment: These are 2 lines. :) Thanks for your help! I think it is much easier to remember now.